# Inluce Method inside JOptionPane

Tags: java, methods, joptionpane

i want to ask something about put a method inside of an JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.

here i have

```
public Double Result() { 
Double NilaiAkhir = (getNilaiUjianKe1() * 0.20) + (getNilaiUjianKe2() * 0.25) + (getNilaiUlanganKe1() * 0.20) + 
                            (getNilaiUlanganKe2() * 0.20) + (getNilaiTugas() * 0.15);
        return Result;
    }
```

then i want to put this Double Result() inside of JOptionPane

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        Student.Result()
    );
```

but it doesn't allow me to do that, how do i include such a method inside JOptionPane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, Double.toString(Student.Result()));
```

And you can't just return Result in your snippet 1,

but you can return NilaiAkhir, if that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Yes i knew it must return NilaiAkhir, what i ask is the double conversion. 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, Double.toString(Student.Result()));

Thank you, solved.